# Tunnel all remote ports through SSH to local hostname

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I want to access all ports from my VPS on my local machine. I know that I can do `ssh -f myusername@vps -L 1000:vps:1000 -N` to access one port - but can I do that in an easy way (without knowing which ports are on the vps beforehand) that I can type in my local browser `vps.localhost:1000` to access the port 1000 on the VPS? So I need something like `ssh -f myusername@vps -L vps.localhost:vps:* -N`. Basically I want to access `localhost` from the vps through `vps.localhost` on my local machine.

I'm not sure if my question has been asked before - if so please tell me and I'm happy too, I could only find question which asked the opposite of mine, to tunnel all local traffic through the VPS.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use the dynamic proxy option to ssh?  `ssh -D 1234 user@remote` and then configure your browser, mail client, etc to use `localhost:1234` as the proxy, or set it system wide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-D [port]` option. Set your application to use `[port]` as a SOCKS5 proxy (might be a bit hard if the application doesn't support that. Firefox definitely does). Now you can browse to http://127.0.0.1:9001 for example, and you'll end up on the remote box's application listening on port 9001.